# Border in each page while exporting with jspdf

Tags: javascript

In jspdf, when the content is too large and pages get split into multiple pages that it won't apply to all the pages.

Is there any solution to apply border into evenly split pages with border in each page when exporting?

Comment: show your code.

Comment: pdf.addHTML(content,1, 1, options, function() {
  pdf.addPage()
  pdf.save('protocolTest.pdf');

Comment: Here if the content is too large it gets split into multiple page, which is expected but the border also goes to next page.

i want to create border into all the pages.

Comment: I have got the solution for this :-

this is the solution:- 

    for (var i=1;i<pdf.internal.pages.length;i++) pdf.internal.pages[i].push("0.00 
    595.28 841.89 -595.28 re");
    pdf.internal.pages[i].push("S");
    }

Comment: for (var i=1;i<pdf.internal.pages.length;i++){
    pdf.internal.pages[i].push("0.00 595.28 841.89 -595.28 re");
    pdf.internal.pages[i].push("S");
    }